# How to redirect www to nonwww domain for root, but not for subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, cpanel

I have main domain - www.mydomain.com, and want to redirect it to non www version. This part is ok and working.

Code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com, [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I also have subdomains redirected to `anotherdomainnames.com`. This is set by hosting. Have multiple sites on shared hosting.  For example: `domain2.example.com` is `www.domain2.com` and is pointing to folder on my hosting `public_html/domain2/`. I think this is default Cpanel setting for addon domains.

When I have www redirect working, subdomains are not working and pointing to  `example.com/domain2/` instead of `www.domain2.com`. When I comment rewrite code above, subdomains are working as they should.

Is there some way to have working www redirect to non www domain, and also have working subdomains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to redirect the `www` subdomain (ie. `www.example.com`), rather than anything that isn't the bare domain (which you are currently doing) then just check for the `www` subdomain in the redirect. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now all your other subdomains won't be redirected as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working great.